# JQuery long animation - dividing into sections

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a 15+ page JQuery animation clickthrough.  The client wants it to autostart and if left untouched, the animation would play all the way through.  Is there anyway to do this in steps or segments, such as, play this section, when finished, play next section, so on and so on till the end?

Comment: It would be helpful to include some of the code so it is clear what sort of animation we are talking about.  Without seeing the code it seems that just using the callback of animate would be sufficient.

Comment: So the code is basically a background image fade-in, text fade-in and animate left, but 15+ times.  Do you know an example of a callback of animate.  My worry is, I don't want to have to figure out in milliseconds how long the delays/fades should last. If I could do them in segments or sections it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use callbacks:

```
$("something").animate({stuff}, duration, function(){
    // CALL NEXT STEP HERE, THIS EXECUTES WHEN ANIMATION COMPLETES
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/